# Setting attributes for a nested resource with hidden fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many, nested-forms

A `recipe` has many `meal_plans`. I have a form that attempts to create a `meal_plan` for the `recipe` I am currently viewing. I have two attributes that I'd like to set for that `meal_plan` with hidden fields. The values are being set correctly in the DOM, but they aren't saving to the database.

**recipes/show.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for [@recipe, MealPlan.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "Upcoming" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user["uid"] %>
    <%= f.submit "Create Meal Plan" %>
  <% end %>
```

**meal_plan.rb**

```
class MealPlan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

**recipe_rb**

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :meal_plans, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meal_plans
  ...
end
```

**recipes_controller.rb**

```
...
def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(
    :name, :link, :ingredients, :image_url,
    meal_plans_params: [:recipe_id, :user_id, :status]
  )
end
```

**meal_plans_controller.rb**

```
class MealPlansController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    @meal_plan = @recipe.meal_plans.create!(params[:meal_plan_params])

    redirect_to @recipe
  end
end
```

**Example Result**

```
<MealPlan id: 10, recipe_id: 1, user_id: nil, status: nil, created_at: "2018-05-26 21:51:11", updated_at: "2018-05-26 21:51:11">
```

The hidden fields for `user_id` and `status` do have values when I look at those fields in the inspector. I can't figure out why those fields aren't saving.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Looks like I needed to use `<%= form_for([@recipe, @recipe.meal_plans.build]) do |f| %>` instead of `<%= form_for [@recipe, MealPlan.new] do |f| %>` in my form.